# How do I receive API Throttling Warnings?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, throttling, facebook-rest-api

We need to fetch mutual friend data for each one of our new users. (We're currently doing that through the REST API.) In load testing for an upcoming traffic surge, we ran into API throttling, which breaks our production site. Oops!

In the Insights -> Diagnostics pane, it looks like they issue throttling warnings before they actually throttle. Is there some way we can monitor those limits in code so that we back off gracefully?

Comment: No you can't...  Just don't hog the API ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to watch for the two errors coming back, then put your next call on a wait timer.

- **API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS**    Application request limit reached
- **API_EC_USER_TOO_MANY_CALLS**   User request limit reached

See: http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks! That gets the errors; do you know how the warnings come back?

Comment: Facebook returns those in the response from their servers, just like they do with any other error.

Comment: This did not answer the question. The warnings did not come back as errors in any of our tests. The errors did, of course, but by then it's too late.